# ReactJS How to actively pass state values to components in App.js

Tags: reactjs

In my App.js I have the following code

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            url: config.Url,
            tables : [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() { 
        axios.get(this.state.url + '/tables')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.status === '200') { 
                    const tables = response.data;
                    this.setState({ tables });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error ' + error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <Header tables={this.state.tables}/>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

While calling the Header component the header state is not set and hence the values are not receiving inside the header. What should I change to get the table state values in my Header component? I tried with `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` functions and both gives same response.

Comment: Can you please show the Header component? Are you sure that you get data from your backend call?

Comment: Yes I get the data from the backend. No other issues with the codes, Its just because of the asynchronous character of reactjs. I just want to know how to overcome this?

Comment: "In practice, `componentDidMount` is the best place to put calls to fetch data" https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: If your component is already mounted and `this.setState({ tables });` actually gets called, that should trigger a rerender of that component. Which means the `render` function gets called. Which means the Header component receives new props. Which means the Header component gets rerendered. So do your initialization in `componentDidMount`, the rest looks fine to my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine other than you need to use `componentDidMount` instead of componentWillMount. setState will have no effect in componentWillMount, which is why you aren't seeing any changes.

Also, take a look at this article: https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/

Comment: I have tried with both `componentWillMount` and `componentDidMount` as I mentioned in my question and both gives same result that I get empty array of `tables` inside my `Header`

Comment: have you debugged to ensure response.data is not null, as well as, used react dev tools to check if your `<Header />` comp is being updated via `componentDidMount`? ..and you need to use DidMount.. you cannot use WillMount to set state.

Comment: Inside my `header` component using `React` debugging tool I could find props gives the table array result, but `this.state = {tables : this.props.tables };` the state gives empty array. How can I get the values in the state?

Comment: So the problem seems to be inside the Header component. Can you please share the full code?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to set initial state of tables to null and in render method check whether 'tables' is null or not. Because you are fetching remote data and by the time React renders the page, data may not be fetched and assigned to tables.

```
render() {
let tablesToProps = <p>Loading..</p>
if(this.state.tables) {
    tablesToProps = <Header tables={this.state.tables} />
} 
return (
    <Router>
        <div className="App">
            {tablesToProps}
            <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
            <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, independent of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillMount`, on the first step you need validade table with is empty array with `if (!this.state.tables.length) {`, see full code:

```
import React from 'react';

class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            url: config.Url,
            tables : [],
        };
    }

    componentWillMount() { 
        axios.get(this.state.url + '/tables')
            .then(response => {
                if (response.data.status === '200') { 
                    const tables = response.data;
                    this.setState({ tables });
                }
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error ' + error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.tables.length) {
            return <div>Loading</div>;
        }

        return (
            <Router>
                <div className="App">
                    <Header tables={this.state.tables}/>
                    <Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
                    <Route exact path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard}/>
                </div>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```